# undefined method `concert_id' for #<FollowUp::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x00007f8d481b3dc0> Did you mean? concat

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a model of follow_ups and volunteers as:

```
class FollowUp < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :volunteer
  belongs_to :member
  belongs_to :concert
end

class Volunteer < ApplicationRecord
  enum type: [:admin, :regular]
  has_many :follow_ups, dependent: :delete_all
  has_many  :members, through:  :follow_ups
end
```

Now I wanted to print follow_ups by all volunteers.
It was working fine when I tried in rails console i.e `Volunteer.first.follow_ups`
I want to show those value in the form, what I tried is:

```
Volunteer.all.each do |volunteer|
 volunteer.follow_ups.concert_id
end
```

Comment: If I want to get all the follow_ups on the basis of volunteer id then how would I proceed.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To collect such information you should use:

```
volunteer.follow_ups.pluck(:concert_id)
```

**Edit:**

It's very important to note that using `pluck` is more efficient than using iterators like `map` and `each` due to saving server RAM and request time. Then you can print to rails logger:

```
volunteer.follow_ups.pluck(:concert_id).each{|ci| Rails.logger.info ci}
```

**Edit2**

Referring to your text

> I want to show those value in the form

If I understand you, you want to show `concert_id`  of each `follow_up` in the `volunteer` form. in this case you should add

`accepts_nested_attributes_for  :follow_ups`  in your `volunteer.rb`
then:

```
<%= form_for @volunteer do |f| %> 
   <%= f.fields_for :follow_ups do |form_builder| %>
      <%= label_tag "custom_label", "follow up id : #{form_builder.object.id}, concert_id : #{form_builder.object.concert_id}%>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The `fields_for` helper will iterate through all `follow_ups` , then you can get the object for each `follow_up` using `object` which allow you to deal with object directly and get your `concert_id` attribute from it.

Comment: @JackSengar actually you don't have a single resource for learning. you can go ahead for railscasts.com and gems documentations on Git hub. In fact I am trying to have deep understanding for rails through making real projects which I believe is the only way effective :-)

Comment: If I want follow_ups on the basis of volunteer id then how would I proceed ??

Answer (score 2):

The `has_many` relation denotes a one-to-many association. Instead of returning a single object, it returns a collection of `follow_ups`.

That said, you can't do `volunteer.follow_ups.concert_id`, because `follow_ups` is an Active Record collection. Make an iteration instead:

```
volunteer.follow_ups.each { |follow_up| puts follow_up.concert_id }
```

[The Ruby on Rails documentation has great content about Active Record Associations.](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference)